# Any way to just view conflicts in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to just view conflicts in Visual Studio 2012, without merging or checking in. In 2012 you used to be able to *Get Latest Version* then go to the pending view and click the show conflicts icon.

I'm keen know if you can do this without any add-ons / external commands, i.e. just using what Visual Studio 2012 standard installation has, without for example either of the following:

Team pilgrim:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222

Or:
tf checkin

Comment: Please review the answers given and consider changing your Accepted Answer - urk_forever's answer seems to be the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "Compare To" option in the right click menu. You can choose to generate a diff between any two versions.

Alternatively, you can do basically the same option with 2012. You can get latest, which will throw any conflicts that exist between the local version and the server version. Conflicts can then be resolved locally, and then either discarded or checked in.

To remove automatic conflict resolution:

`Ctrl+Q --> "Conflict" --> ENTER --> Uncheck "Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated"

Comment: I am aware "Compare To" functionality, but this is a file by file approach and not really what I'm after.                                   The other option you mention is what I've tried, however, when I do it all conflicts are auto-resolved (So far I haven't had any that are not able to be using 2012). What I'd like is to have the option of auto-resolving or not. I suppose then if I have to use *Get Latest* to open the "show conflicts"  view that won't be the end of the world. Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Thanks, I like the Ctrl+Q short-cut, never used it before. I wish it was bit friendlier though.

Answer (score 47):

I was just searching for an answer to this myself, when I found out how you can do this. Here is how to can just view conflicts.

Go to the Team Explorer and select Pending changes. In the Pending changes window there is a dropdown menu named Actions, click that menu and in the menu is an option Resolve conflicts. 
Click that option and a window will be opened showing all conflicts in the workspace similar to the resolve conflicts window of VS2010.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The tab that opens is where the old "Get All Conflicts" button has moved to. Thanks.